# Linked list in file read\write

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I have a project in c to do a movie maker and i put frames and i need to do option to save the project and open it again and enter again frames how i do that?

this is the structs

```
typedef struct Frame
{
char*       name;
unsigned int    duration;
char*       path;  
} Frame;


// Link (node) struct
typedef struct FrameNode
{
    Frame* frame;
    struct FrameNode* next;
} FrameNode;
```

this is the option i need to do i did all except the save and open option

open path
Add new frame
Remove a frame
Change frame index 
Change frame duration
Change duration of all frames
List frames
Play movie!
Save project

Comment: You can not store those addresses because they will point to garbage in the next session, you should find a way to serialize your frames (maybe using indexes?)

Answer (score 0):

Saving will require you to write to a file. You can step through your linked list and at each node write to a file something of the form `(name,duration,path)` and then to open you would just read from the file. See [this tutorial page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm) for info on how to read and write from a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `save` and a `load` function:

```
void save(Frame frame){
    FILE *file = fopen("/path/to/save.txt", "w");
    if(file != NULL){
        fwrite(&frame, sizeof(Frame), 1, file);
        fclose(file);   
    }
    else
        printf("Error %d\n", errno);
}

Frame load(void){
    Frame frame;
    FILE *file = fopen("path/to/save.txt", "r");
    if(file != NULL){
        fread(&frame, sizeof(Frame), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
        printf("Error %d\n", errno);
    return frame;
}
```

And then in your `main` function:

```
int main(void){ 
    Frame f = {
        .name = "my_frame", 
        .duration = 60, 
        .path = "/path/to/frame"
    };
    save(f);
    Frame g = load(); // It will load f to g
    printf("%s %d %s\n", g.name, g.duration, g.path);
    return 0;
}
```